# Extracting parts of an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have lists with expressions like this one: `{-DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 1}], DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 0}]}`. `DTMomentum2` is just an undefined function such that the minus sign does not get distributed into the `{0, 0, 1}` vector. What I want is `-DTMomenta[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}]` in the end, I want to collect all complex valued factors up front in a product and then all three-vectors in a list.

I have tried using `Cases`, and that works for the first one to extract the momenta:

```
Cases[#, DTMomentum2[p_] -> p] & /@ {-DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 1}], DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 0}]}
```

The output is `{{{0, 0, 1}}, {}}`, it did not work with the second one for some reason.

I have tried with a simple `ReplaceAll`, but then I get the minus sign into my vector:

```
{-DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 1}], DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 0}]} /. DTMomentum2[p_] -> p
```

Output is `{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 0}}`.

As long as all `DTMomentum2` expressions come with some factor in front, the following function does what I want:

```
MomentumProductToMomenta2[factors_] := Block[
   {momenta, scalar},
   momenta = Flatten[Cases[#, DTMomentum2[p_] -> p] & /@ factors, 1];
   scalar = Times @@ (factors /. a_ DTMomentum2[p_] -> a);
   scalar * DTMomenta @@ momenta];
```

But as soon as there are terms in the list of *factors*, it just gives an empty list. Changing the pattern to `a_ DTMomentum2[p_]` will absorb the minus sign, but that pattern will fail. Including both patterns give strange results with more terms popping up.

How can I get the coefficients that I want?

Comment: Something like `Apply[Times, #[[All, 1]]] DTMomenta[#[[All, 2]]] &[{-DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 1}], DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 0}]} /. a_. DTMomentum2[v_?VectorQ] :> {a, v}]`?

Comment: Yes, that works! After adding the `.` to my `a_`, my version also works. Thanks so much for pointing to that optionality!

Comment: @MartinUeding Since JM's comment seems to solve your problem, consider writing it up as a self-answer, so your question shows up answered for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Will this simple correction to your 1st approach work for you?

```
expr = {-DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 1}], DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 0}]};
Cases[expr, DTMomentum2[args : {__}] -> args, All]
```

> `{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is another one:

```
expr = {-DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 1}], DTMomentum2[{0, 0, 0}]};
Abs[ToExpression[StringDelete[ToString[#], {"DTMomentum2[","]"}]]] & /@ expr
```

> {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}